# Methods Limit 65k - Google Play Services and ADT

Tags: android, android-multidex

I've seen some questions about it ( [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589560/how-to-avoid-65k-method-limit-while-using-google-play-services) and since [I can't use gradle in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16747412/2652124), I don't know another option) but I don't have any idea to solve it.

So, here is the thing: I updated my ADT and my Play Services to implement the new way to get the user's location (I'm using ADT). Since I did it, I'm facing the problem that I have more than 65k methods in my project. I tried to change the proguard as [Android Developers recomends](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#split), but nothing happens. So, maybe the proguard isn't enabled in my Android app! I tried to see it [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html), but I realized that I don't have the proguard.cfg file in any of my projects!

How can I solve it? I just use few things in Play Services (GCM and Location).

Comment: Do you use the most recent version of GS?

Comment: Its like Eclipse is been deprecated (it has) and they only support Android Studio/Gradle. Maybe switching over is a good idea.

Comment: @mklimek yes I do! Before using it I didn't have any problems. But I had to use it because I updated my way of getting the user's location.

Comment: @RenanBandeira Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @f470071yes I did, Now I use Android Studio and making this move helped me to take a lot of things out of my project, such as sublibraries inside google play services.